# simple Frogger game MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to create a simple frogger game, but when I run my code in MIPS, it throws the error

> ```
> Frogger line 39 column 2: "addi": Too many or incorrectly formatted operands. 
> Expected: addi $t1,$t2,-100`
> ```

```
.data
World: .ascii "____f____"
XCoord: .byte 4
under: .ascii "_"
frog: .ascii "f"

// function that displays "world" string   
emitworld:
addi $ra, $ra, -4($sp)
sw $ra, 0($sp)
jal emitseq

lw $ra, 0($sp)
addi $ra, $ra, 4($sp)
jr $ra
```

Comment: which MIPS emulator do you use?

Comment: maybe just store the value of the addition in some register before moving it to the stack? (I am assuming `-4($sp)` is the destination, i don't really remember MIPS assembly syntax)

Comment: @JanusTroelsen Mars MIPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you can see from [documentation](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/addi.html), the third value has to be an immediate.

try [add](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/add.html) instead.

Comment: yeah, you also need to store it on the stack separately, you can use `sw` for that. `-4($sp)` is not a register, it is an address and only works with `sw` and `lw` if i remember correctly. you first calculate everything in registers, then save it on the stack.

Comment: for example `add $ra, $ra, $ra` doubles the value of `$ra`. after that, save it on the stack

Comment: please accept the answer by clicking the arrow below the arrows on the left side